# delimiter on getline() doesnt work properly

Tags: c++, delimiter, getline

i have a simple code that gets name of user as an array with getline() public function. when it reaches to char '$' i want to stop getting input from user and go to next line.but immediately after reaching char'$'(my delimiter)it ignores line 5 and runs line 6 and i don't know why!!!

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout

int main () {

char name[256], title[256];
std::cout << "Please, enter your name: ";
std::cin.getline (name,256,'$');                         //Line 3
std::cout << "Please, enter your favourite movie: ";
std::cin.getline (title,256);                            // Line 5
std::cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;  // Line 6
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input you give the program? What is the output you get? What is the output you expect? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) doesn't handle terminators other than newline. Consider using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: How do you expect the computer to read your mind and stop reading input when seeing the `$` character? Never once in your code do you specify any sort of delimiter.

Comment: Sounds like what you *really* want is to read a line of input, then tokenize it. Things to research: tokenizer, lexer, parser.

Comment: "ignores line 5 and runs line 6 " if you are going to refer to line numbers, please number your lines.

Comment: sry.i had missed '$' as third argument in getline func

Comment: What, exactly, is the input that this program is seeing? Chances are there's a newline immediately after the '$' character, so the second `readline` sees an empty line.

Comment: dude im noob and i know it.could u plz explain more? what do u mean that what my input is? the input is the name that user enters(line 3)

Comment: Do you write two words as a name or one? Because if you put first and second name then the getline will read first and last names as seperate tokens.

Comment: @Volt -- no, `getline` doesn't separate input on whitespace, only on the delimiter.

Comment: @noob -- When you ran the program you typed something at the console. That's what the calls to `getline` would read. What did you type?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- `basic_istream::getline` has two overloads. One doesn't take a delimiter and the other one does.

Comment: i typed jack$ and what i saw on screen was this==>>Please, enter your favourite movie: jack's favourite movie is

Comment: @peter Becker--actually it didnt let me enter the movie name

Comment: @noob -- typical consoles are line-oriented; they look for the end of a line before passing any input to the application. I'll bet that you typed "jack$" **followed by the enter key**.

Comment: @peter Becker--again u R right bro.but i still dont understand why it ignores line 5. what i want to happen is that the console ask the movie name and copy it in title variable.btw what shall i do to gain this. so sry if im wasting your time by my foolish questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess your input looks like this:

```
> ./myProg
Please, enter your name: noob$
lease, enter your favourite movie: Top Gun
noob's favourite movie is 
>
```

Here we see that you entered: `noob$<return>` followed by `Top Gun<return>`.

The problem is that the input the computer is seeing is:

```
noob$\nTop Gun\n
```

OK. So what is happening in the code.

```
std::cin.getline (name,256,'$');  // This reads upto the '$' and throws it away.
```

So your input stream now looks like:

```
\nTop Gun\n
```

Notice the '\n' at the front of the stream.
Now your next line is:

```
std::cin.getline (title,256);  // This reads the next line.
                               // But the next line ends at the next new line
                               // which is the next character on the input stream.
                               // So title will be empty.
```

To fix it you need to read off that empty line.
A better way to fix it is to not require the name to be terminated by `'$'`. User input is usually better done a line at a time. As the user hits `return` the buffer is flushed and the stream actually starts working. The program is not doing anything (apart from waiting) until that buffer is flushed to the stream (this is usally on return but can happen if you just type a lot).

Comment: yeah u R right.entering a name doesnt need to be terminated by '$' but i was trying to learn how to work with that function.finally i fixed it by duplicating line 5 which means i wrote line 5 twice in my code.you really helped dude.wish u the best.

Comment: I would recommend you read all user input with `std::getline(<stream>, <string>)`. Once you have the line in a string then parse the string to get the information you want out of it. Either with searching or putting the line into a `std::stringstream` so that you can split the line into sections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
.....getline(title,256,'$')
//                      ^
//                      |
// this is where the delimiter goes in your function call
```

Comment: yeah u are right.but when i add this to getline(name,256), it ignores line 5 and  title variable will be empty when i print it on screen

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work like this:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout

int main () {

char name[256], title[256], endOfLine[2];
std::cout << "Please, enter your name: ";
std::cin.getline (name,256,'$');                         //Line 3
std::cin.getline(endOfLine, 1);
std::cout << "Please, enter your favourite movie: ";
std::cin.getline (title,256);                            // Line 5
std::cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;  // Line 6
return 0;
}
```